# How do you combine different if answer == '' '' strings in Python?

Tags: python

I'm a complete beginner in Python and programming in general but I'm working on a short RPG game. I'm using

```
answer = input(" ")

if answer == "a":
```

I want to combine certain answers from within a decision tree so if you answer with "a" at one at one point in the decision tree, for example, it will bring you to a previous point in the decision tree which has the same outcome so I don't need to re-write everything. To clarify, I have several

*answer = input(" ")* (s)

which are numbered as answer0, answer1, and so on. My goal is to have it so if you reply to answer1 with a certain response, it will bring you back to one of the outcomes within answer0 (since they have the same outcome and it would be easier if I didn't need to rewrite everything). I have gotten a few comments saying to look into functions and loops which I will. Hope this update can clarify my goal a bit more.

Comment: Hi Anisa, I believe you need to add more detail. What do you mean by thread?

Comment: Have a look at the wonderful concept of _functions_.

Comment: Where are "threads" coming into play here? Do you really mean "threads"?

Comment: Likely what you need is simply if statements and function calls. I don't think that she actually means "threads" given her statement that she's a complete beginner.

Comment: Something like `if answer in ("a", "b", "c"):`? Definitely going to need more detail on what you're trying to accomplish, update your example in your question.

Comment: Look up both functions and loops! That'll get you on your way!

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is that you want to revert to a previous choice, eg. like a 'go back', for instance if you walked to point A and wanted to walk back to point B.

I suppose you could do:

```
def walktopointA():
    # whatever you want the player to do
    # they make a choice, leading to the execution of foo():   
def walkbacktopointB():
    # this is your choice
    answer = input(" ")
    if answer == "a": # if they want to go back
        walktopointA() # goes back to previous function
```

I would also recommend looking up functions in python, eg. on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)